# parameter list ("*") with lazy "by-name" parameters?

Tags: scala, optional-parameters, callbyname

I can:

```
scala> def foo( f: => String) = println(f)
foo: (f: => String)Unit
```

and I can:

```
scala> def foo( f: String*) = f.map(println)
foo: (f: String*)Seq[Unit]
```

but I can't:

```
scala> def foo( f: =>String* ) = f.map(println)
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but identifier found.
       def foo( f: =>String* ) = f.map(println)
                       ^
```

nor

```
scala> def foo( f: (=>String)* ) = f.map(println)
<console>:1: error: no by-name parameter type allowed here
       def foo( f: (=>String)* ) = f.map(println)
                ^
```

Is there some other way to do what I want?  Why isn't this allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the `=>` means that the parameter is passed by name. What you have tried isn't allowed simply because `=>String` is not an actual type (as opposed to say `()=>String`) and you cannot make an `Array[=>String]`. Given that a variadic parameter `x: T*` is under the hood handled as an array containing all the parameter's values (as in `x: Array[T]`), this is the reason why not being able to create a `Array[=>String]` (which does not make sense) also means  that a variadic parameter `f: (=>String)*` is not possible.

This problem can be worked around using a little wrapper class:

```
implicit class ByName[T]( getValue: => T ) extends Proxy {
  def apply(): T = getValue
  def self = apply()
}
```

Then change the signature of your method like so:

```
def foo( fs: ByName[String]* )
```

When calling your method with multiple arguments, all the arguments will be implicitly wrapped into a `ByName` instance, and then you can call `apply` to get the actal value:

```
def foo( fs: ByName[String]* ) = fs foreach { f => println( f() ) }
```

Given that `ByName` extends `Proxy` for simple things such as calling `toString` or testing equality you don't even have to call `apply`. Thus you can simply do:

```
def foo( fs: ByName[String]* ) = f foreach println
```

Comment: this looks cool.  I realized my question was a duplicate, but I like this answer.  I'm using 2.9 though which doesn't support `implicit class`, can this be made to work in 2.9?

Comment: looks like I just need the implicit to be separate from the class def.